# How to do Power BI cumulative line plot?

Tags: powerbi

How can I turn this graph into a cumulative line graph? Seems like a simple thing but I cannot find the options in the visualization options?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in visualization. You need to create a *cumulative* measure something like this, and use it in the visualization.

```
Cumulative Total =
CALCULATE(
    [your measure],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Here, `'Calendar'` would be replaced with the actual name of date dimension table in your model.